# How can I access a string resource in XAML?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've defined `AppResource.resx` in my main app folder. Inn it i have defined the string name `OVERVIEW` that holds a string.

I've then added it in my App.xaml like this:

```
    <!--Application Resources-->
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AwesomeApp.WP" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>
    </Application.Resources>
```

And added it i a textbox:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.OVERVIEW, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" />
```

However, that `TextBlock` is empty... guess there is a broken link? Im working on localizing my app.

LocalizedStrings looks like:

```
    public class LocalizedStrings
    {
        public LocalizedStrings()
        {
        }

        private static AppResources localizedResources = new AppResources();

        public AppResources AppResources
        {
            get { return localizedResources; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong Path. Either change "LocalizedResources.OVERVIEW" into "AppResources.OVERVIEW" in XAML, or rename the AppResources property into LocalizedResources in the .CS.

BTW, I was so disappointed there's no support in Blend for that, I usually expose localized strings as the read-only properties of my view models, and use data binding to access them. For me, it worked better compared to that long "{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.OVERVIEW, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" expressions.